# modeling self referencing nodes in EMF and edit them with ECP

Tags: eclipse-emf, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I'm trying to model a network with EMF. 
The network should be made up of nodes connected to each other.
Each node should have one or many connections to the others, like a mesh network.

The model should be editable by the EMF Client Platforms (ECP) Demo Application.
When the user creates nodes, in ECPs model-explorer, he/she can set the connections to the other nodes, preferably in a list.

First try was a self-reference, but the problem is there are no bidirectional self-references. This results in, not seeing the connection from the opposite node.

My next idea was to use an intermediate connection class, which leads to another problem. I would like to create this connection automatically without a connection class appearing in the model-explorer. Which would be possible to achieve in the generated EMF viewer, but not in the ECP demo application I'm using.

Third Idea: The only way I can think of solving the last idea, is using a tableControl in the view of the node, to edit the connection class in there. But then the problem with hiding the connection class in the model-explorer remains and the connection class appears in the project folder (highest level) and not in their containing class (in my case a network class).

Doe's anyone have some ideas, how to solve any of my problems?

**edit: additional information**

The connections between the nodes are by definition full duplex.
And the graph should afterwards be used as input for a shortest path algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first try is the good one. Actually, you can model opposite in Ecore. To do so, you have to model two `EReferences` towards the same object (so two reflexives references), then set the property `eOpposite` of one of your `EReference` to the other one.

Here is a simple metamodel with the `eOpposite` set: https://repository.genmymodel.com/vincent.aranega/NodeGraph

In the Ecore-XMI, it looks like this (note the `eOpposite` value):

```
<eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EReference" xmi:id="_pwXZhv1pEeW9zv77lynsJg"
    name="references" upperBound="-1" eType="#_pwXZg_1pEeW9zv77lynsJg" eOpposite="#_pwXZiv1pEeW9zv77lynsJg"/>

<eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EReference" xmi:id="_pwXZiv1pEeW9zv77lynsJg"
    name="relatives" upperBound="-1" eType="#_pwXZg_1pEeW9zv77lynsJg" eOpposite="#_pwXZhv1pEeW9zv77lynsJg" />
```

With this metamodel, you are able to create a `Graph` that contains many `Node`. Each node can `reference` other nodes. If a `Node` `A` as a reference to another named `B`, the `relatives` collection of `B` is automatically updated with `A`.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. But now it's like an in and an out connection. Is it a good idea to automatically add the references to the relatives (in the generated code), so that i can step through the graph only by using one of the references.

Comment: ou i forgot: and if so, where would be the place to implement this double add (or better synchronization of reference lists). BTW: the original question is answered, so i mark yours. thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your requirement right. With the solution I gave you, you can step through the graph using only the `references` collection for example. The two collections are automatically synchronized, if you put an element in one of the two collection, the other one will be updated.

Comment: I mean, using only the `references` collection to step through the graph, lets me do it only in one direction. If, for example, there would be a good way from `Node A` to `Node B`, but the user makes a connection by adding `Node A` to `Node Bs` reference collection, I won't find the way by starting at `Node A`. To overcome this problem, I was thinking about syncing the two collections of the node itself (the instances), but with ECP I have problems to find the right hook. Maybe customizing a control would be a solution.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. A solution could be to model an extra reflexive `EReference` and set it as `[0..*]` and `derived`. The derived collections are computed and only their empty method are generated in the EMF code. This way, in the metamodel generated code, you could compute the new `EReference` value by performing a union between `relatives` and `references`. As this collection is derived, it would be "read-only". Hope this helps.